# Implicit declaration of mkdir

Tags: c, function, makefile

For my question let's suppose I have two functions, both of them with the prototypes on a .h file in a library folder, and the implementation in a .c auxiliary file (shown below), and I will use both of them in my program.

**calsis.c**

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 #include "include/calsis.h" /* Extern header */ 

char folder_name[30] = "Information";

void no_args() /* Function 1 */
{
  printf("Hello, world!\n");

   if ( mkdir(folder_name, S_IRWXU) == -1 )
    perror("Can't create a new folder");
}

void with_args(char *foo) /* Function 2 */
{
   printf("Hello, world!\n");
   printf("Name: %s\n", foo);

   if ( mkdir(folder_name, S_IRWXU) == -1 )
    perror("Can't create a new folder");
}
```

For something I will do later, I need in both functions to create a folder with mkdir, but, in the generation of the object file **calsis.o** by the compilation of the .c file with the implemented functions, the compilation with GCC gives me a warning that the **mkdir function is implicity declared**.

Any idea I can remove this warning?

Comment: Did you `#include <sys/stat.h>`?

Comment: You should [determine](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) the relevant header for `mkdir`, and make sure you `#include` it.

Comment: @Kunal, Yes, it is the header that I was looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't included the header for `mkdir`:

From man(2) mkdir:

```
SYNOPSIS
       #include <sys/stat.h>
       #include <sys/types.h>

       int mkdir(const char *pathname, mode_t mode);
```

Comment: It is also necessary the header `#include <sys/types.h>`? Because I saw in another place (http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v1r12/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zos.r12.bpxbd00%2Frtmkd.htm) that only the first header is necessary.

Comment: mode_t is in sys/types.h. It's necessary if you intend to use mode_t. The page you linked is for ZOS where, it seems, mode_t is part of sys/stat.h itself. The man page I pasted is for Linux. So it depends on your platform whether you require to include it or not.

Comment: In my case it's Fedora, so, yes, I included it.