# How to remove warnings in C?

Tags: c

I write program in C and it does not show any errors but it has some warnings which I cannot find out how to fix.

First working is

> printf uses %d and expects *int* argument but *pos* is *long int*.

```
printf("Kernel load error: kernel %s is smaller then 11000 bytes. %d bytes loaded total.\n",files[count].name,pos);
```

Second is

> implicit declaration of function 'mkdir' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|

```
mkdir("kernels");
```

similar problem , this is shortened:

```
char * path = "kernels";
buildKernels(&path, files, count, &binariesSizeTotal);
```

implementation:

```
bool buildKernels(char ** path,FILES * files, int count ){
  strlen(path);
...
}
```

incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function 'strlen' [enabled by default]|

Two more:

> *implicit declaration of function 'buildKernels' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|
>
> implicit declaration of function 'loadKernels' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]|*

both functions are declared in headers. I am not sure what mean the "implicit declaration". What the compiler expects from me? How to fix these errors?

Last problem which I did not succeed to fix:

```
while( token != NULL )
   {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      token = strtok(NULL, s); // char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
   }
```

this gave me warning warning:

> comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]|

Comment: Your question/title: `How to remove warnings in C?` -> answer: `Just write good code!`

Comment: The first warning should be pretty obvious, the `"%d"` format expects an expression of type `int`, but you provide one of type `long`. Update the [`printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) format to the correct one.

Comment: It's probably `strlen(*path)` instead of `strlen(path)`. Make sure you `#include <string.h>`. Also declare `bool buildKernels(char ** path,FILES * files, int count );`.

Comment: The other warnings are obvious as well, you don't have any declarations of the `buildKernels` and `loadKErnels` functions, so when you call those functions the compiler have to *implicitly* declare them for you (by guessing what arguments they take, which can sometimes be wrong). You need to declare the functions you call before calling them. If the functions are declared in header file, then do you actually include the correct header files?

Comment: It's best to ask a single specific question per post.  That will help future SO readers find the information they need.

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed two or three problems (and one new arise :-( ), but what I cannot fix are the warnings with missing declaration. I include the headers for buildKernels so they should be declared. The mkdir problem stays unsolved. The result == NULL comparison between pointer and integer stays unsolved too.

Comment: @user1141649 There is no such comparison like result == NULL in the code snippets of your post. It seems that result has integral type or As i pointed out in my post maybe NULL is redefined.

Comment: The last problem which I have written in the question was not that one which I wanted to paste. But it is similar. The result is result from fwrite(): `result = fwrite(binaries[n], binary_sizes[n], 1, f);  
        if ( result == NULL ) ...`

Comment: I've try this `size_t result;if ( (result = fwrite(binaries[n], binary_sizes[n], 1, f)) == NULL) printf("Write data failed, %s\n",fname);`
but it still give the same warning :-(×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use format specifier `%ld` for variable `pos`.

Include headers where functions `mkdir` and `buildKernels` are declared or at least include their declarations before their calls.

Also take into account that function `buildKernels` is called with four arguments

```
char * path = "kernels";
buildKernels(&path, files, count, &binariesSizeTotal);
```

but decalred with three parameters

```
bool buildKernels(char ** path,FILES * files, int count ){
...
}
```

So this can be the reason of the error.

Function `strlen`. expects an argument of type `const char *` while you pass argument of type `char **`

```
bool buildKernels(char ** path,FILES * files, int count ){
strlen(path);
```

Either declare parameter `path` as having type `char *` or correctly call function `strlen` like

```
strlen( *path );
```

As for the last warning then if token is a pointer then the code is valid. You should show the full warning message. Or maybe NULL is defined in C++ style instead of C style. You should not define NULL yourself.

Comment: Thanks, it was why compiler implicitly declared the function buildKernel because I had one more argument then declared &binariesSizeTotal

Comment: The headers are included in the .c file where mkdir is used: `#include <sys/types.h> // mkdir
#include <sys/stat.h> // mkdir` but the warning stays there

Comment: @user1141649 The warning messages usually show in which module they do not see function declarations. So see the messages.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479746/implicit-declaration-of-mkdir What I miss is this: `int mkdir(const char *pathname);` I had no idea I need to declare the function. It is also useful to know that sys/types.h is for mode_t so I do not need it

Comment: @user1141649 All is written in my post. So there was no need to search any "solution" somewhere else. You need simply to check whether the function is declared before its usage.